# Listview Color change not working when list is long

Tags: android, listview, listviewitem, getview

I have a `ListView` of times and I want to change the colors of the `ListItem` as time goes by, it works when the hour of the day is in the mornings like 8 or 9 even 10, but as the hours grow to 5 or 6 at night it stops working. they all the colors are as they originally were. Its weird.

I know that my code to check if the hour has passed is fine.
Here is my `getView()` method.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;
    LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();

    if (convertView == null) {

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_adapter_tab, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();


        SharedPreferences prefs = convertView.getContext().getSharedPreferences("com.example.edonfreiner.siddur", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        if (prefs.getBoolean("isHebrewSet", true)) {
            holder.txtSecond = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.zman);
            holder.txtFirst = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.time);


        } else {
            holder.txtFirst = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.zman);
            holder.txtSecond = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.time);


        }
        convertView.setTag(holder);


    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    this.convertView = convertView;

    HashMap<String, String> map = list.get(position);
    holder.txtFirst.setText(map.get("First"));
    holder.txtSecond.setText(map.get("Second"));

    convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) convertView;
    if (ZmanimListTab.getUpComingZmanPosition() > position) {
        for (int i = 0; i < relativeLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
            ((TextView) relativeLayout.getChildAt(i)).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#77FFFFFF"));
        }
    }else{
        for (int i = 0; i < relativeLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
            ((TextView) relativeLayout.getChildAt(i)).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
        }
    }

    return relativeLayout;
}
```

Here is my method to get the list index of where to change the color:

```
    private void getNextAvailableZman() throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {

    for (int i = 0; i < listZmanim.length; i++) {
        Date targetDate = ((Date) complexZmanimCalendar.getClass().getMethod((String) listZmanim[i]).invoke(complexZmanimCalendar));
        if (targetDate.after(now)) {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            upComingZmanPosition = i;
            return;
        }
    }
    upComingZmanPosition = listZmanim.length;
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should add how you are changing the colors base on time. Should post your controller code.

Comment: Check to see any values are null. That tends to be my problem. Other then that, refactoring more to MVC tends to help my coding out alot.